# Python: Unable to install hdbcli library on Python 3.8 installation

Tags: python-3.x, database, hana

Unable to install [hdbcli](https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/#description) library on Python 3.8 Windows installation.
Python version is 64-bit to be compatible with the wheel.
The "win32" in the Python console header only indicates that it is a Windows system. Actual Windows architecture is 64-bit as seen in systeminfo output.

I've tried installing:

- via the wheel (link below)
- via pip (pip install hdbcli)
- a previous version of the library (pip install hdbcli==2.4.171)

None of which were successful.
I feel there is something obvious I'm missing

---

**Error information:**

- ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hdbcli
  (from versions: none)
- ERROR: No matching distribution found for
  hdbcli

**Python information**

- version: 3.8.2
- pip version: 20.0.2
- Python console header: Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

**System information**
As from systeminfo:

- OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
- OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
- System Type:               x64-based PC

**hdbcli information**

- [hdbcli-2.4.182-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/7f/4efdb1d47d9833302e843100babf5ec93371f0032fe662320f4b345e017b/hdbcli-2.4.182-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl)

Comment: Determined this isn't working for Python 3.8.0 or Python 3.8.1 (both 64-bit) either.
After trying with Python 3.7.0 and 3.7.6 no issue was seen.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rename the file from hdbcli-2.4.182-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl to hdbcli-2.4.182-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl and install once again with pip install hdbcli-2.4.182-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

hdbcli wheels (prior to version 2.4.191) were built with old versions of pip/setuptools/wheel that use different ABI tags for Python 3.8 on Windows.

If you can't update to 2.4.191 or rename the wheel, you can work around this issue if needed by downgrading to pip 19.2.2 or lower.

These packages expect the updated 'cp38' format (only available with hdbcli 2.4.191 and later) :

```
setuptools >= 42.0.0
wheel >= 0.33.5
pip >= 19.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case hbcli was not compatible with python3 beacuse I wasn't able to install hdbcli library with python 3.10. However it is compatible with python 2.7 so go ahead and install latest version of python 2.7 and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

What worked for me was installing an older version of Python, namely 3.6.15 and setting it up for the project (i.e. added it as project interpreter in Pycharm).

Then, I could successfully install hdbcli.